# Como criar dinamicamente várias vezes o mesmo layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu criei um layout chamado com um botão "+" no final de forma que eu gostaria que, ao clicar no botão, fosse adicionada um novo LinearLayout abaixo do layout atual com o mesmo conteúdo, possibilitando o cadastro de mais de um item sem ficar gerando novas telas.

Mal sei por onde começar...

Pelo que entendi, no evento OnClick do botão "+", preciso criar um novo LinearLayout e posicionar abaixo do layout que contem o botão atual depois inflar ele com o conteúdo do layout "endereco" usando o Inflate. Mas não estou conseguindo codificar isso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Meu Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    style="@style/Layout_Fragment_Port"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/Layout_Fragment_Port"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/regpet_edt_name"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:hint="@string/label_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/regpet_spn_pettype"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/regpet_spn_petbreed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/regpet_lbl_petsize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@string/label_petsize"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/regpet_txt_petsize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/regpet_lbl_petsize"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/regpet_lbl_petsize"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/regpet_lbl_petsize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/regpet_lbl_hairsize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/regpet_lbl_petsize"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/regpet_txt_hairsize"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/regpet_txt_hairsize"
            android:text="@string/label_hairsize"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/regpet_txt_hairsize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/regpet_btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/regpet_txt_hairsize"
            android:background="@color/colorPetCareLight"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_content_description"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_delete"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/regpet_btn_newpet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/regpet_txt_hairsize"
            android:background="@color/colorPetCareLight"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_content_description"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_new" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/regpet_frame"
    style="@style/Layout_Fragment_Port"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

O evento do botão:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout newlayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    newlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    newlayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ConfigFragment.openFragment(new RegPetFragment(), newlayout.getId(), getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.title_reg_pet));
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicou no botao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Conteúdo de ConfigFragment.openFragment:

```
    public static void openFragment(Fragment fragment, @IdRes int containerViewId, FragmentManager manager, String tag){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

A mensagem de erro:

```
Can't add fragment RegPetFragment{977258d} with tag null to container view with no id
```

Comment: Tem como adicionar o código de seu layout?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um simples exemplo do que eu entendi :

Temos um botão para adicionar e um `LinearLayout` que irá receber os `EditText` para o usuário adicionar um novo endereço:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/adicionar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/valores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:text="VALORES" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Componentes da tela
     */
    private LinearLayout containerAddress;
    private ImageButton adicionar;
    private Button valores;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adicionar = ImageButton.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.adicionar));
        valores = Button.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.valores));
        containerAddress = LinearLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.containerAddress));


        adiconar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addEditText();
            }
        });

        valores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getValues();
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Adiciona um EditText no containerAddress!
     */
    private void addEditText(){
        //Criamos o EditText
        final EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        //Seta os parametros
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
        //adiciona no containerAddress
        containerAddress.addView(editText);
    }


    /**
     * Pegamos os valores dos EditText' adicionados na tela
     */
    private void getValues(){
        // Pegamos a quantidade de filhos que o containerAddress tem..
        int total = containerAddress.getChildCount();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Total de itens: "+total);

        //Vamos iterar os filhos de containerAddress
        for(int pt=0; pt < total; pt++){
            // Pegamos o item
            final View view = containerAddress.getChildAt(pt);
            //Cast para um EditText
            final EditText editText = EditText.class.cast(view);
            //pegamos o valor
            final String addressText = editText.getText().toString();
            Log.w("MainActivity", addressText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, esse código é fantástico... Já me deu uma luz sobre como a coisa funciona... Como eu tenho um layout um pouco mais complexo do que alguns simples EditTexts, seria possível fazer a mesa coisa com um layout pronto ao invés de ficar colocando os componentes individualmente um a um?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui!!!

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout newlayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    newlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newlayout.setId(ConfigFragment.generateViewId());
    LinearLayout parentlayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.regpet_frame_main);
    parentlayout.addView(newlayout);
    ConfigFragment.openFragment(new RegPetFragment(), newlayout.getId(), getChildFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.title_reg_pet));
}
```

Certamente novas dúvidas surgirão!